# How to slice output of a neuronal network

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I constructed a generator CNN which has the output `(1, 3328, 1)`, but I would need `(1, 3326, 1)` so just 2 neurons/outputs less. I don't think that I can achieve it by changing parameter of the existing net.

But I thought, it would be great just to cut out the last 2 neurons of the last layer.

But does someone know how to "slice" a layer in a NN?

```
Model: "functional_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 500)]             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 26624)             13338624
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_18 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 26624)             0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_12 (Reshape)         (None, 832, 1, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_12 (Conv2DT (None, 1664, 1, 16)       4624
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (Batc (None, 1664, 1, 16)       64
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_19 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 1664, 1, 16)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_13 (Conv2DT (None, 3328, 1, 8)        1160
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (Batc (None, 3328, 1, 8)        32
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_20 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 3328, 1, 8)        0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_13 (Reshape)         (None, 3328, 8)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)            (None, 3328, 1)           25
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 3328, 1)           0
=================================================================
Total params: 13,344,529
Trainable params: 13,344,481
Non-trainable params: 48
_________________________________________________________________
Out[40]: (1, 3328, 1)
```

Comment: At least you can share the summary of the model, so someone else can think about it.

Comment: Sure, but if one knows about what is meant, I thought that info is superfluous. but okay, I will add it.

Comment: I will try out, whether this works then for training too - or did you used it in your past?

Comment: If you wanna use this for training then use the first line of code which I shared below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do this**

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.input , model.layers[-1].output[:,:-2,:])
```

**Simply do this**

```
model.layers[-1].output[:,:-2,:]

#This will simply return 
[None, 3326, None]
```